# Unable to understand how this mongo query service command works on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, mongodb

Our admins have given us the following command to launch the MongoDB service from our (non-sudo) accounts:

`mongo resteam-mongo-cluster-001:27017 -u mongo-admin -p --authenticationDatabase admin`

Could someone please break this down for me, as I'm a somewhat Linux newbie, but more importantly because the admins are always super busy here and if I have to tweak this later on for our team's purposes, I don't want to be calling them up.

The

Comment: This isn't the "command to launch a service", this is the command to connect to a database. In this line "Mongo" is a script or a program, "resteam-mongo-cluster-001" is a host and 27017 is the port number mongodb is listening on. Mongo client is told to use username "mongo-admin" and be prompted for a client password (the -p switch). On the mentioned host, your admins have created a database called admin, in which user mongo-admin was created. Substring "--authenticationDatabase admin" tells client to look for credentials of user mongo-admin in database admin. You don't tweak this command.

Comment: @Kitet Why didn't you post your comment as an answer? Seems to address the question without needing any further clarification ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the "command to launch a service", this is the command to connect to a database. In this line, `Mongo` is a script or a program, `resteam-mongo-cluster-001` is a host, and after a colon, `27017` is the port number mongodb is listening on the above host. Mongo client is told to use username `mongo-admin` and be prompted for a client password (the `-p` switch). On the mentioned host, your admins have created a database called admin, in which user mongo-admin was created. Substring `--authenticationDatabase admin` tells client to look for credentials of user mongo-admin in database admin.

Because this is a connect string to an existing service, You don't tweak this command, your admin will adjust it when he changes any parameters of the service.